# Для чего нужны EJB?

Tags: java-ee, ejb

Начал изучать ejb, и каждый раз задаюсь вопросом: что есть в ejb такого, что обычными способами не сделать?
Транзакциями можно в хибернейте управлять, сервисы можно на jax-ws делать...
Получается, что только для очередей можно использовать?

Comment: Сначала надо закончить изучение. Может в середине или ближе к концу книжки станет ясно. EJB не решает ни тех проблем, для которых придуман хибернейте, ни тех, для которых придуман jax-ws. Если можете обойтись без EJB - хорошо. Меньше кода набивать. Но кому-то он всё ещё нужен. Очереди - это что? JMS, если что, тоже без EJB прекрасно себя чувствует.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12872683/what-is-an-ejb-and-what-does-it-do

Comment: EJB - удалённый вызов и транзакции. По-умолчанию вызов каждого метода - это транзакция автоматически. Самому не надо делать commit|rollback. C MDB получателей мессаг удобно делать. Всего одна функция и сразу получает свою мессагу. Не надо самостоятельно заботиться о подключении к серверу. Опять-таки выполняется в контексте транзакции автоматически. Так что за счёт EJB всё-таки можно экономить на строчках кода.Для этого всё и задумано

Answer (score -2):

EJB компоненты управляются EJB-контейнером, который управляет их состоянием (создает, уничтожает и пр. еще и кэширует Entity), управляет транзакциями и прочее, и все это работает по умолчанию, в большинстве случаев без каких либо настроек и кодирования со стороны программиста.
JAX-WS/JAX-RS - используется для взаимодействия систем на различных платформах (например, между Java и PHP), и по производительности значительно уступает EJB (только между или внутри Java-приложениями).